# Want to create a scratch card view using native script any one know

Tags: angular, nativescript

Want to create a scratch card view using native script in angular. 
Initially, the card should be an image view. When user scratches it, it should show some values, exactly like google pay's scratch card.

Comment: You might try the [nativescript-drawingpad](https://github.com/bradmartin/nativescript-drawingpad) plugin, instead of adding color, try to use transparent color to eliminate the color from background.

Comment: You can try this plugin, https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-scratchview